# Classify images into groups that have a similar structure(texture/shape)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Hi I am trying to group images that have a similar structure(texture/shape). I am avoiding learning methods. Some of the methods I have encountered are Principal Component Analysis. I am still trying to compute the efficiency of these methods. I wanted to know if there are more methods that i can try. 
The images are generated after a bit of processing.
An example of two different groups is as shown below.

[image]

An example of two images belonging to the same group is shown below.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define 'structure' ?

Comment: Could you post some examples to show us what type of structures you are looking at? Also, isn't PCA considered a machine learning method? :)

Comment: I was referring to methods such as SVM etc. I am sorry if my language is not sophisticated enough. I am just a beginner and not very familiar with vision terms.  As for examples I m looking for pattern (gray scale). Ill Edit my question with some examples.

Comment: Your question is very unclear - to me at least. Basically, you are saying *"here are two dissimilar things"* - and it's pretty obvious the two are not the same, but then neither would a picture of an orange be the same. What aspects have to match for the images to be considered similar - the average brightness? The shape? The colours?

Comment: I am looking for similar shaped images. I mean an orange and an apple(both are circular)  can go together but not an apple and a banana. Unless i can distinguish between an apple and orange solely from its shape.

Comment: So it is actually similarity in terms of their geometric shape you are after? Please update your question with that. It will help future readers. Could you post two images that should be the same and two images that should not be the same? This will aid the testing...

Comment: Also, you added that you are looking for similar patterns. I'm reading that as texture. I don't think you are after similarities in texture, are you?

Comment: Since they look a bit like digit shapes to me, perhaps looking at the machine learning tutorials around the MNIST set could be helpful.

Comment: I highly recommend Principal Component Analysis.  Other options that are similar to PCA include Single Value Decomposition and Autocorrelation.  Both PCA and SVD work with the eigenvalues of the image.